# React native vs Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, react-native, xamarin.forms

We need to build a commercial mobile app that is supported on iOS, Android and UWP platforms. We have been looking at react native and xamarin forms to do so. What is more recommended/preferable technology to implement this?

Reasons why we wanted to use react native in first place:
1) more experience in JavaScript 
2) Some of the UI designs in our mobile app includes having cross platform features which by default could be native to either IOS or android. Such as having icon badges on tab items, having toggle search box in navigation bar. On react native we found these were more easily achievable by git hub plugins but in xamarin forms you need to write custom renderers to achieve so.

Reasons why started investigating on xamarin forms: Since the app needs to run windows phones too, we stared using react native XP plugin to support that. But end prototype on windows phone wasn't very impressive in terms of performance and user experience of some of react native plugins we have used. Plus we also had to do quite a bit UI customisation in terms of specifying width/heights to make components work.

Comment: can you elaborate on where the performance problems were on Windows Phone? Several React Native Windows users have shipped on phone with no reported performance issues, so knowing what hardware model and the profiler showed would help me give an informed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been develop on Xamarin a few years now. My honest opinion is that there is a lot of third party libraries and components that only has support for Android and iOS only. Maybe you you check out what third party libraries you need and work back from there.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Phones are an honest target for you going forward, unless you can limit to those capable of UWP apps (Win 10 Mobile) then scratch Xamarin from the list. Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 support is deprecated and will be dropped soon from Forms.